# display table name in textbox when we click on button

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

can you please tell me how to retrieve table name from mysql server database when we click on button using c#.net.
for example i am having **table name register** in my database when i click on button **get table name** , only one table name should be displayed.
i have tried the following code

```html
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   TextBox1.Text = dt.TableName[0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for ?

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

string myConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                            "DATABASE=mydatabase;" +
                            "UID=user;" +
                            "PASSWORD=mypassword;";

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SHOW TABLES;";
MySqlDataReader Reader;
connection.Open();
Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (Reader.Read())
{
    string row = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
        row += Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ", ";
    Console.WriteLine(row);
}
connection.Close();
```

Comment: i want table name from the database instead of rows.

Comment: Reader.GetValue(0).ToString() provides the table names.